# Magento full screen product image zoom in and zoom out not working

Tags: magento2, product-images

I have installed Porto theme. When I visited a product page and click on the image, it goes into full screen, which is exactly as per requirements. When I try to zoom in or out of the image using the magnifier glass icons,nothing happens.

I have no clue why this is the case.

See example on this webpage:
http://34.83.184.119/lightcatcher-solar-100w-12v-mono-solar-panel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable Zoom for fullscreen in view.xml

Copy `view.xml` file from

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```

add `view.xml` to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/etc/view.xml
```

You can find out magnifier and change as per requirements.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the attempt. The problem is that the zoom in and zoom out buttons after full screen is not doing anything. It is just not functioning on my setup.

Comment: Hi, the view.xml doesn't control js function of the zoom button nor does it say anythig about it.

Comment: @Vrajesh Sir, I am facing same issue in magento 2.4.1, I tried this solution but still facing the issue, please help me

Comment: Which issue you are facing ?